# Fiddler not capturing requests made via FireFox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, fiddler

Fiddler isn't capturing any requests from Firefox but it is capturing requests from IE or Chrome. I have the FiddlerHook add-in from Telerik installed and it is enabled.

Comment: @CodeCaster: The question is very different from all others and very pertinent. I know how to force fiddler to show a request to localhost. In the last few years, I've also gone through the link you just linked to. This is not my question. My question is very specific. Please have some patience in reading the question before marking it for closure or as a duplicate.

Comment: Please read the question. It has nothing to do with requests to localhost. Please read things carefully.

Comment: @CodeCaster: You got an axe to grind? They are different questions. What's your problem?

Comment: When I installed fiddler, there was an add-on fiddler that was automatically disabled by firefox. You may have to go in and enable this addon, Im not sure, its called "FiddlerHook".